# Random variable transformation formula not working

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

Let there be a probability density function

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4}\quad x\in(0,4)$$
$$f(x) = 0\quad \text{elsewhere}$$

Its distribution function therefore is
$$
       F_x(x)=\frac{x}{4} \quad x\in(0,4)
$$

$$
       F_x(x)=0 \quad x<0
$$

$$
       F_x(x)=1 \quad x>4
$$

The task is to find the distribution function of a transformed variable
$$Y=-\ln(X)$$

Here are my steps:
$$F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y) = P(-\ln(X) \le y) = P(\ln(X) \ge -y)=\\
P(X\ge e^{-y}) = 1-P(X\leq e^{-y}) = 1-F_X(e^{-y}) =\\
1-\frac{e^{-y}}{4}$$

From this follows that the density function of the transformed variable is
$$f_Y(y)=(1-\frac{e^{-y}}{4})' = \frac{e^{-y}}{4}$$

However, there is a rule that states that the following is true:

$$f_Y(y) = f_X(h^{-1}(y))\cdot (h^{-1}(y))'$$

This does not hold for me though, because upon plugging in my values, this is my result:

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot (e^{-y})' = \frac{1}{4}\cdot (-e^{-y}) = -\frac{e^{-y}}{4}$$

The result is different from the one I obtained by differentiation. What happened?

Comment: In that rule, there should be an absolute value, i.e $f_Y(y) = f_X(h^{-1}(y)) \cdot \left| (h^{-1})'(y) \right|$.

Comment: @DominikKutek ...oh, thank you

Comment: Note that the rule only applies for monotonic functions (when without the absolute value, only for increasing functions)